# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error when making an HTTPS/HTTP request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, post, aws-lambda

Here's the code of my AWS Lambda function:

```
console.log('Loading function');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const https = require('https');

const data = JSON.stringify({
secretKey:"someSecretKey",
userType:"someCoolUser",
})

const options = {
 hostname: "backend-staging.programmingpathshala.com:8080/rest/admin",
 path: '/sendEmailToUsers',
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
 }
}

 exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var dataString = '';
    const req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        dataString += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
                callback(null,dataString);
      });
    });
    req.write(data)
    req.end();
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
   }
```

When I test my API using postman it works fine. But when it is called from lambda function I get the following error:

[image]

Also, When I run the same API using ngrok and use its link in my lambda function it works then too.

Comment: Are you sure your api works with `https`?

Comment: using ngrok it does. but it's hosted with HTTP. Also, I tried both HTTP and HTTPS getting the same error.

Comment: I see. Then is your `hostname` valid?. Usually, it would be just `backend-staging.programmingpathshala.com`, then you would have `port` option in `options` and `path` would be `/rest/admin/sendEmailToUsers`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Please write that as the answer. I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, the `options` should be:

```
const options = {
 hostname: "backend-staging.programmingpathshala.com",
 port: 8080,
 path: '/rest/admin/sendEmailToUsers',
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
 }
}
```